# How can I execute `date` inside of a crontab job?

Tags: cron, quoting, command-substitution

I want to create a log file for a cron script that has the current hour in the log file name. This is the command I tried to use:

```
0 * * * * echo hello >> ~/cron-logs/hourly/test`date "+%d"`.log
```

Unfortunately I get this message when that runs:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I have tried escaping the `date` part in various ways, but without much luck. Is it possible to make this happen in-line in a crontab file or do I need to create a shell script to do this?

Answer (score 306, accepted):

Short answer:

Escape the `%` as `\%`:

```
0 * * * * echo hello >> ~/cron-logs/hourly/"test$(date +\%d).log"
```

This also uses `$(...)` instead of the deprecated `` `...` `` syntax for command substitution and quotes the expansion of said command substitution.

Long answer:

The error message suggests that the shell which executes your command doesn't see the second backtick character:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching '`'
```

This is also confirmed by the second error message you received when you tried one of the other answers:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ')'
```

The [crontab manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) confirms that the command is read only up to the first unescaped `%` sign:

> The  "sixth"  field  (the rest of the line) specifies the command to
> be run.  The entire command portion of the line, up    to  a  newline  or
> `%` character, will be executed by `/bin/sh` or by the shell specified in
> the `SHELL` variable of the cronfile.  **Percent-signs  (`%`) in the**
> **command, unless escaped with backslash (`\`), will be changed into**
> **newline characters**, and all data after the first `%` will be sent  to
> the  command  as standard input.

Comment: Why did they implement this behaviour for the percent sign?

Comment: @rubo77 Some commands can accept input from stdin, so this behaviour of % might be useful when calling such commands. I have never used it myself, but perhaps you might want to pass "y" over standard input, to answer a yes/no confirmation prompt from the command, or pass some commands to an ftp client, to initiate the transfer of a file.

Answer (score 25):

If you would like to make the date formatting string as a variable (to avoid duplicating the whole string), **DO NOT** escape `%` and **DO NOT** put it in `$()`

For example, while declare the string, just write:

```
DATEVAR="date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"
```

Then, write cron statement with `$($VARIABLE_NAME)` like this:

```
* * * * * /bin/echo $($DATEVAR) >> /tmp/crontab.log
```

Thanks to *cyberx86*, [her/his answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/339814/how-do-you-set-a-date-variable-to-use-in-a-log-for-crontab-output) at **ServerFault** might be more completed:

Comment: This answer has issues with quoting, and it's unclear where to set the `DATEVAR` variable and how to do it in such a way that it support e.g. format string containing spaces.

Comment: Quoting is fixed. You put the definition in the head of your crontab file

Answer (score 9):

You can also put your commands into a shell file and then execute the shell file with cron.

**jobs.sh**

```
echo hello >> ~/cron-logs/hourly/test`date "+%d"`.log
```

**cron**

```
0 * * * * sh jobs.sh
```

Comment: This is generally a good idea, but does not help where output must be redirected to a datestamped logfile from the crontab itself. If the output redirect is done inside the shell script, cron still tries to capture the output and email it to you, causing this problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/222512/cron-info-no-mta-installed-discarding-output-error-in-the-syslog (hint: you DO NOT need to install an MTA, but you will need to move the output redirect into the crontab command, even if this is not as pretty as you might like)

Comment: ... on the other hand, it looks like you can still redirect to `>>dev/null 2>&1` on the job in crontab, and then do different redirects on lines inside the shell script

Answer (score 5):

In cron, you can use this simple syntax:

```
*/15 01-09 * * * sh /script.sh >> /home/username/cron_$(date -d"-0 days" +\%Y\%m\%d).log 2>&1
```

Comment: Output date format will retrun like cron_20180123.log

Comment: (1) What are you saying that hasn’t already been said by the accepted answer?   (2) Your answer is much more complicated than the question.  For example, you added the `-d` option, which is not used in the question (and you did not explain it).  How do you justify calling this “simple syntax”?

Answer (score 4):

### A basic solution:

- use `$()` for executing `date` command and return output
- format datetime to UTC, escape the `%` character with `\`
- add `2>&1` at the end for streaming both `stdout` and `stderr` into that log file

#### Example:

```
* * * * * echo "Test crontab log" > /tmp/crontab.log.$(date --utc +\%Y\%m\%d_\%H\%M\%SZ) 2>&1
```

#### Output:

```
ls -lh /tmp | grep log

-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu  ubuntu    17 May  4 05:06 crontab.log.20190504_050601Z
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu  ubuntu    17 May  4 05:07 crontab.log.20190504_050701Z
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
0 5 * * 3 /data/script.sh > /data/script_`date +\%y\%m\%d`.log 2>&1
```

Comment: What are you saying that hasn’t already been said by the accepted answer? Are you saying that it works better without quotes than it does with quotes? (Hint: that’s very unlikely.)

Comment: The accepted answer simply doesn't work for me. This one does.

Comment: Perhaps it’s the `2>&1` that’s significant here (and not featured in other answers), rather than the quotes.

Comment: Using `2>&1` is (almost always) a good call for logging, and probably does solve whatever problem was going on in `/data/script.sh`, but it is only tangential to the OP's question about using the `date` command in cron