# Mplayer cronjob doesn't work

Tags: cron, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I execute `date` inside of a cron tab job?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29578/how-can-i-execute-date-inside-of-a-cron-tab-job)

I made a cronjob to record a stream every friday between 23pm and midnight. Only somehow this doesn't seem to work.

the cronjob is

```
57 22 * * 5 timeout -s SIGINT 66m mplayer -dumpstream http://82.201.100.23:80/slamfm -dumpfile /var/www/HOA-NL/$(date +"%U-%Y").mp3 >> /home/david/HOA-NL-LOG 2>&1
```

This doesn't work while the following works

```
57 22 * * 5 echo "foo" > /home/david/barr
```

and the following works either (timing out echo doesn't make sense, I know. It's just an example)

```
57 22 * * 5 timeout -s SIGINT 66m echo "foo" > /home/david/barr
```

Now I'm wondering why this doesn't work.. It doesn't give me a error or a message in /home/david/HOA-NL-LOG

Comment: Does your command work if you run it from the CLI?

Answer (score 8):

You've committed the classic error of using `date +%foo` in a cron job, causing you to bump into cron's most baffling feature. Clearly documented in `man 5 crontab` but often overlooked, here it is:

> The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or %
>   character, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell
>   specified in the SHELL variable of the crontab file.
>   Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash
>   (\), will be changed into newline characters, and all data
>   after the first % will be sent to the command as standard
>   input.

Backslash your percent signs!