# How to find out why my cron didn't run?

Tags: linux, logs, cron

This is the content of root's crontab:

```
0       23      *       *       0-4     /usr/sbin/rtcwake -time `date --date="+16 hours" +"%s"` -m mem
```

This is set to fire off that command every Sun-Thu at 11pm. The command is essentially a suspend for the next 16 hours while I'm at work to save power. I've test the command with smaller times (30, 60 seconds) and it works. However, when I wake up in the morning and check my machine, it's still running.

Here's what's in the logs:

```
Jul 24 23:00:01 gallactica CRON[5033]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/rtcwake -time `date --date="+16 hours" +")
```

So does this mean it ran? Why didn't it actually work?

Comment: That log entry means it ran. Although the log line seems incomplete at the end (copy&paste problem?). If the command produced any output, the user who owns the crontab (root in this case) would have gotten an email

Comment: I am wondering whether the `%s` in the command has been mangled by `printf` in the log, and maybe in the actual command that was executed too to cause it to fail.

Comment: @MichaelHomer that makes sense actually. Tonight I'm going to try dumping this line into a separate file instead. I don't think it was a copy paste problem so this seems like the most probably cause.

Comment: See [How can I execute `date` inside of a cron tab job?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29578/how-can-i-execute-date-inside-of-a-cron-tab-job)

Comment: @steeldriver yup that looks like it may be my issue. I'll give it a try, thanks.