# Passing a command with arguments to a script

Tags: shell, zsh

I am trying to write a **shell script** that receives as an input a **command with arguments** and runs it.

As an example, I am hoping to use this in `cron` as follows:

```
0 11 * * * my_wrapper.sh "task_name" "command arg1 arg2 arg3 ..."
```

The details of what `my_wrapper.sh` does don't matter, but it is a `zsh` script and I want it to receive `command arg1 arg2 arg3 ...` and invoke it. Note that the arguments may contain single quotes, double quotes, etc.

What is the proper way of passing and receiving commands with arguments to scripts?

### Update:

On the command line in zsh, @Gilles' first solution works great:

```
#!/bin/zsh
task_name=$1
shift
"$@" > /path/to/logging_directory/$task_name
```

and then invoking `> my_wrapper.sh date "%Y-%b-%d"`  from the command line does the job.

However, when I try to use it as follows in `cron`:

```
CRON_WRAPPER="/long/path/to/my_wrapper.sh"
0 11 * * * $CRON_WRAPPER "current_date.log" date "+%Y-%b-%d"
```

It doesn't work.

### Final update (problem solved):

As explained in Gilles' answer, **`crontab`** requires **escaping** any `%` signs. After changing the above to:

```
CRON_WRAPPER="/long/path/to/my_wrapper.sh"
0 11 * * * $CRON_WRAPPER "current_date.log" date "+\%Y-\%b-\%d"
```

it worked. All set.

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to pass the command as an argument instead of invoking the command in the script and passing the arguments to it when you run the script?

Comment: Thanks @cremefraiche. Not sure I follow, but just in case: `my_wrapper.sh` is meant to be a generic wrapper for cron jobs. For now it only logs the output on a predefined folder (the folder's name is given by the current date, and the logging filename is  `task_name` followed by the current timestamp). I also hope to email myself a note saying that the task  `task_name` finished correctly. Are you suggesting to not use a generic wrapper to do all this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two choices: you can pass a program to execute with some arguments, or you can pass a shell script. Both concepts can be called “a command”.

A **program with some arguments** takes the form of a list of strings, the first of which is the path to an executable file (or a name not containing any slash, to be looked up in the list of directories indicated by the `PATH` environment variable). This has the advantage that the user can pass arguments to that command without worrying about quoting; the user can invoke a shell explicitly (`sh -c …` if they want). If you choose this, pass each string (the program and its argument) as a separate argument to your script. These would typically be the last arguments to your script (if you want to be able to pass more arguments, you need to designate a special string as an end-of-program-arguments marker, which you then can't pass to the program unless you make the syntax even more complicated).

```
0 11 * * * my_wrapper.sh "task_name" command arg1 arg2 arg3 ...
```

and in your script:

```
#!/bin/zsh
task_name=$1
shift
"$@"
```

A **shell script** is a string that you pass to the `sh` program for execution. This allows the user to write any shell snippet without having to explicitly invoke a shell, and is simpler to parse since it's a single string, hence a single argument to your program. In an `sh` script, you could call `eval`, but don't do this in zsh, because users wouldn't expect to have to write zsh syntax which is a little different from sh syntax.

```
0 11 * * * my_wrapper.sh "task_name" "command arg1 arg2 arg3 ..."
```

and in your script:

```
#!/bin/zsh
task_name=$1
sh -c "$2"
```

Comment: Thanks @Gilles, your first solution works well, but does not seem to work well when using parameter expansion in `cron`. Really odd. I added an update to the OP to reflect this.

Comment: @user815423426 [You need to quote the percent signs for cron](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29578/how-can-i-execute-date-inside-of-a-cron-tab-job).

Comment: Thanks. Apparently that isn't the problem (I quoted the argument in the update to the OP) I have the same problem after quoting the percent signs, or with e.g. `python -c "2+2"`

Comment: @user815423426 I don't see anything obviously wrong. Add `set -x; : "{$^@}"` at the top of the script to get a debugging trace and post the content of the email that cron sends you.

Comment: I just realized that the link asks to **escape** the percent sign. I was quoting things as `date "+%Y-%b-%d"` I should have read your link better. All set!

Answer (score 4):

The best way to handle this is to pass the actual command args to your wrapper as args instead of as a string. You can call your wrapper like this:

```
my_wrapper "task_name" command arg1 arg2 arg3
```

`my_wrapper` would contain the following:

```
task_name=$1
shift # remove the task_name from the command+args
"$@" # execute the command with args, while preserving spaces etc
```

Comment: Thanks, if I try `my_wrapper "get_date" date '+%d'`, it tries to invoke `date +%d` (it drops the single quotes), so the `date` command fails (I know this in part because I enabled `set -x` on the receiving script). Hmm... I wonder if [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/176329/4531) to this question: [Running commands stored in shell variables](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176326/running-commands-stored-in-shell-variables?noredirect=1#comment291297_176326) can help.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no nice way around the single quote problem. Bash will parse single quotes, which means those quotes will not exist in your wrapper script. You would need to escape the quotes in date +\'%d\'

Answer (score 1):

I was having I think a similar issue with dash options and I came across this question here in my searching so I wanted to share what helped me. I was using the following crontab:

```
0 23 * * * sudo -u myname /home/myname/bin/buildme.sh -f >> /home/myname/log.txt
```

And inside the bash script I was using this to get the -f option:

```
while getopts ":f" opt; do
    case $opt in
        f)
            force_full=1
            ;;
        \?)
            echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
            ;;
    esac
done
```

So I noticed that the option wasn't being honored when I ran this through cron for some reason.  Well, adding /bin/bash to the cronjob fixed it right up.  The new crontab is:

```
0 23 * * * sudo -u myname /bin/bash /home/myname/bin/buildme.sh -f >> /home/myname/log.txt
```