# Adding timestamp into log file via cronjob command

Tags: bash, cron, logs, timestamps

I try to run git pull command with loging output message to file every 5 minutes.

But i got error like this,

```
(root) CMD (cd /var/www/sites/ && git pull origin master | sed -e "s/^/$(date +\")
(CRON) error (grandchild #1111 failed with exit status 2)
```

My cronjob command as follows.

```
*/5 * * * * cd /var/www/site/ && git pull origin master | sed -e "s/^/$(date +\"%d-%m-%y\ %T\"), /" >> /var/log/crond/site.log
```

How can fix it?

Comment: Do you know what's causing the error?

Comment: I'm not sure but i think pipe operator cause the error.

Comment: It's the unescaped `%` probably.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29578/how-can-i-execute-date-inside-of-a-cron-tab-job . That question is about how to add a date to the output file. This one is about how to insert a date into that file without changing the name.

Answer (score 6):

Note, for some systems a `%` is special in a crontab: from crontab(5) on my system

> The  "sixth"  field (the rest of the line) specifies the command to be run.  The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or a "%" character, will be executed by /bin/sh or  by  the  shell
>   specified  in  the  SHELL  variable of the cronfile.  **A "%" character in the command, unless escaped
>    with a backslash (\), will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first  %  will
>    be sent to the command as standard input.**

I **strongly** recommend using the date format `%Y-%m-%d` -- not only is it [a standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Calendar_dates), it sorts the same lexically and chronologically. Some strftime implementations have a shorthand for it: `%F`

See if your system has a [`ts`](http://man.cx/ts) command

```
cd /dir && git pull origin master 2>&1 | ts "\%F \%T" >> /var/log/crond/site.log
```

To get "real-time" timestamps, you might have to unbuffer the command: (starting to get really ugly)

```
cd /dir && stdbuf -oL sh -c 'git pull origin master 2>&1' | ts "\%F \%T" >> /var/log/crond/site.log
```

Comment: yes, it works on the command line, but *cron* treats `%` specially

Comment: Now, i understood correctly. :) And i fixed my problem. Thanks @glenn :)

Comment: fixed my cronjob timestamp issue

* * * * * www-data sh -c 'php /var/www/example.com/current/artisan schedule:run' | ts "\%F \%T" >> /var/log/laravel_scheduler.log 2>&1