# How to add a user / api token to my crontab

Tags: linux, cron, python

So basically I have a python script that checks a webpage for unassigned tickets and notifies me if there is any. 
My goal is to have a crontab file that runs the `.py` file every 2 minutes.

If I run the `.py` file using the following in terminal:

```
python check.py -u user@email.com -t aaAAAaAAaaAAAa
```

It functions as desired. However I need to figure out how to add the above user and API token, so that every two minutes the crontab runs the `.py` using the user/token.

My crontab so far is as follows

```
2 * * * * /usr/bin/python /Users/usr/Downloads/check-master/check.py
```

If you could point me in the right direction that would be great, or any advice you can give, thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking - AFAIK you should be able to add arguments to commands within a crontab in exactly the same way as you do in the interactive shell (although beware of [any that may contain unescaped percent signs](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29578/how-can-i-execute-date-inside-of-a-cron-tab-job))

Answer (score 0):

os.environ['ZENDESK_API_USER'] = 'user@email.com'
os.environ['ZENDESK_API_TOKEN'] = 'aaAAAAaaaA' (token)

I added that to the script itself, works fine.