# command on crontab not working

Tags: bash, centos, command-line, cron

Command on crontab not working but If I run the same command on terminal, it works.

```
[root@ds backup]# crontab -l
* * * * * find /opt/backup -type f -regextype posix-extended -not -regex '.*('$(sed 's/ /|/g' <<<$(echo {6..0} | xargs -I{} -d ' ' date --date={}' days ago' +"%Y%m%d" | xargs echo))').*' &> /home/ocdn_adm/f.txt

#
#
```

After 2 mins, I run these commands,

```
[root@ds backup]# cat /home/ocdn_adm/f.txt
cat: /home/ocdn_adm/f.txt: No such file or directory
```

Seems like cron command fails to run

But If I run the same command on terminal

```
[root@ds backup]# find /opt/backup -type f -regextype posix-extended -not -regex '.*('$(sed 's/ /|/g' <<<$(echo {6..0} | xargs -I{} -d ' ' date --date={}' days ago' +"%Y%m%d" | xargs echo))').*' &> /home/ocdn_adm/f.txt
[root@ds backup]# cat /home/ocdn_adm/f.txt
/opt/backup/conf-backup-20180407.tar.gz
```

it works, weired. Can I make the command to work on crontab?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I execute \`date\` inside of a cron tab job?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29578/how-can-i-execute-date-inside-of-a-cron-tab-job)

Comment: @user4556274 I tried escaping percentages like `\%Y\%m\%d` but it still fails to work.

Comment: Did you also escape the ampersand ?

Comment: @user4556274 now it works, thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Beware, `cron` does not use `bash` by default. You have to specify used shell, as well as `PATH`. For example:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=~/bin:~/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin

* * * * * find /opt/backup -type f -regextype posix-extended -not -regex '.*('$(sed 's/ /|/g' <<<$(echo {6..0} | xargs -I{} -d ' ' date --date={}' days ago' +"\%Y\%m\%d" | xargs echo))').*' &> /home/ocdn_adm/f.txt
```

While we're at it, I also like to add info about display so commands dependant on X are working:

```
DISPLAY=:0
```

To debug your cron commands you can take a look at syslog, info about them running and possible errors are there:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

Example output of a correct command `xset m 1 1`:

```
May 11 14:29:01 cage CRON[25152]: (Ctrl-C) CMD (xset m 1 1)
```

Comment: Please incorporate the advice about escaping `%` into your answer.

Comment: What glenn said; your sample cron command has un-escaped `%` in it.

Comment: Please edit an answer if you see an error in it. Anyway, thanks for pointing it out, I added escapes.