# cron job not redirect the output to file

Tags: cron

I set the following line in cron job under `/etc/cron.d/find_old_file`

```
* * * * * root  [[ -d /var/log/ambari-metrics-collector ]] && find  /var/log/ambari-metrics-collector   -type f -mtime +10 -regex '.*\.log.*[0-9]$' -printf '%TY %Tb %Td %TH:%TM %P\n' >> /var/log/find_old_file
```

this cron should find the logs that older then 10 day ( but only if `/var/log/ambari-metrics-collector` folder exists )

from some unclear reason we notice that  `/var/log/find_old_file` not created

and when we test it this line works fine on shell bash but not from cron

we also add **2>&1** in the end of the file but this not work

please advice what is wrong in my cron job ?

```
more /etc/cron.d/find_old_file

* * * * * root  [[ -d /var/log/ambari-metrics-collector ]] && find  /var/log/ambari-metrics-collector   -type f -mtime +10 -regex '.*\.log.*[0-9]$' -printf '%TY %Tb %Td %TH:%TM %P\n'   >>    /var/log/find_old_file 2>&1
```

example when we test it on shell bash

```
 [[ -d /var/log/ambari-metrics-collector ]] && find  /var/log/ambari-metrics-collector   -type f -mtime +10 -regex '.*\.log.*[0-9]$' -printf '%TY %Tb %Td %TH:%TM %P\n'
2018 Aug 13 12:54 collector-gc.log-201808130951
2018 Aug 13 04:22 collector-gc.log-201808130403
2018 Aug 01 12:40 gc.log-201808011229
2018 Aug 01 12:40 collector-gc.log-201808011229
2018 Aug 09 15:36 gc.log-201808091332
2018 Aug 09 10:50 gc.log-201808090825
2018 Aug 13 04:02 collector-gc.log-201808130346
2018 Aug 13 16:51 gc.log-201808131358
2018 Aug 01 13:35 gc.log-201808011241
2018 Aug 01 13:35 collector-gc.log-201808011241
2018 Aug 09 15:39 collector-gc.log-201808091332
2018 Aug 02 23:06 gc.log-201808022256
```

when I put this

```
* * * * * root echo test  >> /var/log/test
```

then its works , but not my line as described

so what are happens here?

Comment: Also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29578/how-can-i-execute-date-inside-of-a-cron-tab-job

Comment: Your cron log (/var/log/cron) should also have an interesting entry where the `find` command ends shortly after the `-printf`.

Comment: if sh != bash (eg Debian) then [[ ]] fails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%` sign in crontab [see man (5) crontab](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) has special meaning (newline) and to get your command work you need to escape them.

```
A "%" character in the
   command, unless escaped with a backslash (\), will be changed into
   newline characters, and all data after the first % will be sent to
   the command as standard input.
```

so, your command should be:

```
* * * * * root  [[ -d /var/log/ambari-metrics-collector ]] && find /var/log/ambari-metrics-collector -type f -mtime +10 -regex '.*\.log.*[0-9]$' -printf '\%TY \%Tb \%Td \%TH:\%TM \%P\n' >> /var/log/find_old_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an executable shell file

```
cat /root/bin/find_old_file
    #!/bin/sh
    [[ -d /var/log/ambari-metrics-collector ]] && find  /var/log/ambari-metrics-collector   -type f -mtime +10 -regex '.*\.log.*[0-9]$' -printf '%TY %Tb %Td %TH:%TM %P\n' >> /var/log/find_old_file
```

which you run via cron

```
cat /etc/cron.d/find_old_file
    * * * * * root  /root/bin/find_old_file
```

If a script needs to be reformatted it to suit cron, it is often beneficial move it out of cron.