# add backslash before specific character

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed

we have file with many "%" characters in the file

we want to add before every "%" the backslash

as

```
\%
```

example

**before**

```
%TY %Tb %Td %TH:%TM %P
```

**after**

```
\%TY \%Tb \%Td \%TH:\%TM \%P
```

how to do it with sed ?

Comment: If it's a [cron file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/465556/117549), I would be cautious, in case the creator of the file ever *really* wanted to use % for sending stdin to the job.  Consider [simpler wrapper scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/465575/117549) instead of gambling on precise syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty straightforward

```
$ echo '%TY %Tb %Td %TH:%TM %P' | sed 's/%/\\%/g'
\%TY \%Tb \%Td \%TH:\%TM \%P
```

but you can accomplish the same with bash parameter substitution

```
$ str='%TY %Tb %Td %TH:%TM %P'; backslashed=${str//%/\\%}; echo "$backslashed"
\%TY \%Tb \%Td \%TH:\%TM \%P
```