# Is there a reason to use \+ or \- in date arguments?

Tags: shell-script, cron, syntax

I use `date \+%F\-%T` to show date and time in this format: `2019-08-15-21:34:58`.

From `man date`:

> `%F` full date; same as %Y-%m-%d 
>   
>   `%T` time; same as %H:%M:%S

I recognized no explanation for `\+` or `\-`.

I later understood that the backslashes are escaping, the plus is arguments prefix and the hyphen is just a string-like separation (*date*-*time*),
and also, that some use the simpler `+'%F-%T'` or `+"%F-%T"` instead.

Is there a reason to use + or - in date arguments?

Comment: What happens if you run the command without the backslashes? It produces the same output on my system (date 8.31).

Comment: I remembered I tried it once and recall it worked the same. I understand it should work the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The backslashes do nothing.

The `-` and `+` characters do not need to be escaped, because they are not special in any way in the syntax of any shell.

```
$ set -o xtrace
```

```
$ date +%F-%T
+ date +%F-%T
2019-08-15-11:51:46
```

```
$ date \+%F\-%T
+ date +%F-%T
2019-08-15-11:51:50
```

As you can see in the above trace output, the command that gets executed by the shell is the same regardless of the backslashes. Note too that the trace output is only "debugging output" from the shell and that whatever commands it outputs *generally* are not suitable for shell *input*.

The `+` introduces a `date` format specification. And the `-` is just a literal dash, part of the format specification (will be a dash in the output too).

The command `date \+%F\-%T` is the same as `date +%F-%T`.  You will often also see the date format quoted, as in `date +'%F-%T'`.  This makes no difference here as the format is a single word, but in `date +'%F %T'` it needs to be quoted to keep the shell from splitting the format on the space into two separate arguments to `date`.

What *does* makes a difference is the `%` characters. You would want to escape these if you use them in a crontab specification. See e.g. [How can I execute `date` inside of a cron tab job?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29578/how-can-i-execute-date-inside-of-a-cron-tab-job)

The `%` character was special in the syntax of the `fish` shell prior to version 3.0 (for job expansions) but only when the first character of a word (so not here when after a `+`). Similarly, in `zsh`, a leading `%` character is special in that a `?` following it is not taken as a glob operator (to allow things like `kill %?cmd` without having to quote the `?`), but again that doesn't apply here.

Comment: For some reason though, Busybox's shell escapes the plus-sign when tab-completing.

Comment: @ilkkachu Not for me in that shell. What are you completing?

Comment: just filenames. Actually it seems to escape about everything that's not `a-z0-9_-`, so it's probably just being careful, dunno.

Comment: Note that in the `rc` or `akanga` shells, backslash is not special, so `date +%T` would be different from `date \+%T` there (the latter being treated the same as `date '\+%T'` and so causing a syntax error by `date`)

Comment: Note that some shells' `xtrace` do not output code which when reinput would produce the same outcome, and some could preserve the quoting from the input. So you may want to clarify that your test output there is run from `bash` or any other shell that behaves in a similar way.

Comment: What I meant is that in several shells `date +'%F %T'` and `date +%F %T` for example produce the same `xtrace` output and yet those are two different `date` invocations. IOW, in general, it's not because the `xtrace` output shows the same thing that two commands are equivalent.