# "Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string" only when calling from crontab

Tags: bash, cron

Why do I get this error

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

when calling this in `/etc/crontab`?

```
19 2 * * *   root    for f in $(cat /home/rubo77/list); do date +"%y-%m-%d %T">"$f".datefile; done
```

The list only contains paths to existing directories and those are the first lines in my crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

When I call the `for` commandline on the console in bash I get no errors

Comment: You need to escape the `%` signs - see this related question: [How can I execute `date` inside of a cron tab job?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29578/how-can-i-execute-date-inside-of-a-cron-tab-job)

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape the `%` signs

see this related question: [How can I execute `date` inside of a cron tab job?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29578/how-can-i-execute-date-inside-of-a-cron-tab-job)

You can use this to fix it

```
sed -i 's/%/\\%/g' /etc/crontab
```