# Why does my Backup Cronjob not work?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, docker

I am currently trying to Backup my persistant Docker data once a week.
But somehow my cronjob wont work. Cron has no problem with other jobs. Just with this one and i dont understand why.
I edited the cronjob with my normal user, not root.
The command works if i use it normally in bash.
Anybody got an idea?

0 1 * * SUN cp -r /home/docker /home/brian/docker_backup/alserver_backup_$(date +%y_%m_%d)

Comment: Perhaps this will help: [How can I execute `date` inside of a cron tab job?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29582/65304)

Comment: Yes. Thank you @steeldriver. After reading that post i just put my command into an shellfile and used the file in cron.